# Dart - How to cast a generic templated class?

Tags: dart

In Dart, can one convert a generic templated class of one type to another?

For example, here is a generic templated class that has one member:

```
class Response<T> {
  T data;
}
```

I want to cast the `<dynamic>` variant to something specific, like `<String>`, after I have filled the `dynamic` member with valid `String` data.

For example:

```
final responseAsDynamic = Response(); // Type is Response<dynamic>
responseAsDynamic.data = 'John Smith'; // Type is still Response<dynamic>, but data is String

var responseAsString = Response<String>(); // Type is Response<String>
responseString = responseDynamic; // Error: Response<dynamic> is not a subtype of Response<String>
```

I understand that `Response<dynamic>` is not a subtype of `Response<String>`, but is there a way to tell the compiler that this conversion is ok?

`List` has `cast()`, but there doesn't seem to be anything comparable for `class<>`.

I ran into this while writing a handler for HTTP response data from `Dio`.  A function like `Dio.get()` returns a generic `Response<Map>`, which I want to convert to a specifically typed response like `Response<List<T>>`.

I can get around the issue by simply returning the typed data, instead of trying to to cast the `Response` class.  But this seemed like an interesting generic use-case worth exploring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no automatic way to do the conversion.  You will need to add a conversion function yourself similar to `List`'s `cast` method.  If you don't own the `Response` class, you could create an extension method:

```dart
extension ResponseCast<T> on Response<T> {
  Response<U> cast<U>() {
    return Response<U>()..data = this.data as U;
  }
}
```

and then you could do:

```dart
responseString = responseDynamic.cast<String>();
```

Comment: Ah, makes total sense.  Thanks!

Comment: That does require making a full copy of the object, and you have to manually copy all the members over.  In my code I ended up just using a Tuple to send both the Response and the correctly type Data.  I'll have to keep this cost in mind when using the cast function in lists.  It really ought to be named something like "duplicate", since casting usually comes with the connotation of being in-place, "free".